# Isometry group of low dimensional Alexandrov space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

It is known by the [work of Galaz-García and Guijarro](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4878), that the dimension of the isometry group of an $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space (of curvature bounded below) is bounded above by $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, however little is said about the groups or the isometries themselves.

Is it known what the isometry groups of low dimensional ($n=2,3$) Alexandrov spaces are? Is it known for example for spaces with $\mathrm{curv}\geq0$?

Comment: There are some classifications of 3-dimensional Alexandrov spaces here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3929

Comment: Also  [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0540) from Núñez-Zimbrón on isometries of 3-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think much is known about this. As far as I know, in dimension three a complete answer is only known in the case of spherical space forms: McCullough, Darryl. *Isometries of elliptic 3-manifolds.* J. London Math. Soc. (2) 65 (2002), no. 1, 167--182. [MR1875143](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1875143).